# How to insert empty element in IBM JSF?

Tags: jsf

I tired to create empty `<td>` element in JSF page  under panelGrid tag but no luck. I used below options

```
<h:outputText value="& nbsp;" escape="false"/>
<h:outputText value=" " />
style="margin-left: 5px;"
<h:outputText value="&amp;nbsp;" escape="false"/>
```

At last I used `<!-- empty-->` that resolved problem in my local machine but failed in integrated environment. I also verified that there was no configuration in web.xml to remove comments if any. Still I am not sure why `<!-- empty -->` didn't work in integration environment. I agree this may not be the effective way but I trying to learn whats happening really.

Comment: Oops' <!-- empty -->' some how disappeared while posting the quesition

Comment: [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: This question is ambiguous. To exclude one and other, does CSS `table { empty-cells: show; }` do what you actually wanted?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am trying to add one empty element line where the number of '<td>' is fixed in a particular row('<tr>'). in normal jsp we can just '<td>&nbsp;</td>'.. How can we achieve that in jsf. Please let me know my requirement is not clear.